# Deploying Web-Application on Jboss-Server

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, jboss5.x

Every time we write some code in our project we need to clean project which is going to take some time even if Jboss supports Hot deployment.
Is there any tool/trick which will help us to get our web application deployed within less time?
I am using eclipse Juno and Jboss Application Server 5.1 please guide accordingly.

Comment: We use Jboss-dev studio at work which supports this. It's just eclipse with some plugins, the plugin update site is free though, will try to find you a link...

Comment: Install JBoss Tools (from Eclipse Marketplace) or switch to JBoss-dev studio (in the end it's an Eclipse with jboss tools and other plugins)

Comment: Thanks I think i would go with JBoss Tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use maven to hot-deploy through build script
[This](http://tech.tejusparikh.com/post/10920302006/jboss-hot-deploy-with-maven) might be helpful